# How to use Bootstrap with Material for MkDocs?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

##### The problem

I have a stupid problem that I can't find a solution to... I'm using Material for MkDocs which is a theme for MkDocs. the theme sets the `<html>` font-size to 125% and then uses rems to set font-sizes, padding, etc.

I want to use some Bootstrap components with this theme and though it works fine, everything is scaled up because of the 125% rem base set in the `<html>` tag. The Bootstrap components/code are going to live inside of a wrapper with a `.demo` class like this:

```html
<div class="demo">
  <button class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
</div>
```

##### Part solution

I have a custom.css file where if I set `.demo { font-size: 0.8rem }` the font-size of the button becomes 16px, as it should, but the padding remains the same.

##### Question

How can I manipulate the "scaling" that is done in the `<html>` tag of the theme or can I somehow scale down the padding of the Bootstrap components/contents of the `.demo` class?